# How to align column series bar and independent axis if i fixed column series bar width in winrt xaml column series using c#

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

How to align column series bar and independent axis if i fixed column series bar width in winrt xaml column series using c#

```
private static Style GetNewDataPointStyle( )
{
        Random ran = new Random();
        //Color background = Colors.Blue;

        Color background = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)ran.Next(255), (byte)ran.Next(255), (byte)ran.Next(255));

        Style style = new Style(typeof(Control));
        Setter st1 = new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(background));
        Setter st2 = new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
        Setter st3 = new Setter(Control.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0));
        Setter st4 = new Setter(Control.HeightProperty, 0);
        Setter st5 = new Setter(Control.WidthProperty, 0);
        Setter st6 = new Setter(Control.MaxWidthProperty, 30);
        Setter st7 = new Setter(Control.MinWidthProperty, 30);

        //Setter st6 = new Setter(DataPoint.TemplateProperty, null); // causes exception
        style.Setters.Add(st1); style.Setters.Add(st2); style.Setters.Add(st3); style.Setters.Add(st4); style.Setters.Add(st5); style.Setters.Add(st6); style.Setters.Add(st7);
        return style;
    }
```

My output is:

[image]

Comment: Your output image is missing ...

Comment: i am not able to upload image

Comment: You can upload it to e.g. www.tinypic.com and post a link to that ...

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2ntjzpk/8

Comment: is there any buddy who can give this answer?